# Matplotlib Move y-axis Tick Labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given a plot like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Example data
people = ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Slim', 'Jim')
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
performance = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
error = np.random.rand(len(people))

plt.barh(y_pos, performance, xerr=error, align='center', alpha=0.4)
plt.yticks(y_pos, people)

plt.show()
```

How can I move just the y-axis ticks (not the tick labels) left to a specified degree?

In addition, how would I move the tick labels as well?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean, by "left to a specified degree"? Like you want them to be shorter, or crossing the y axis spine?

Comment: I mean closer to the axis labels, which could mean crossing the, spine.